# jQuery: Convert string to "handle" similar to Shopify's Handleize

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm trying to do the same thing that Shopify's "handleize" does to a string, but with jQuery.

https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/string-filters#handle

Basically I want to convert any string to a handle, so

> Hello, my name is Corey.

would become

> hello-my-name-is-corey

using a jQuery function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, really you'd do this with regex and string replacement, not jQuery.

```
var name = "Hello, my name is Corey.";
name = name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'-');
```

You'll also want to remove *all other* non-alpha-numeric characters, such as invisible characters, most unicode, etc. as that has a high likelyhood of causing similar issues.

```
name.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, '-').replace(/-$/, '').replace(/^-/, '');
```

Comment: Actually you need to remove non alphanumeric characters and adjacent dashes as @grim suggested so `name.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, '-').replace(/-$/, '').replace(/^-/, '');`

Answer (score 2):

I've done a small jQuery extension to slugify strings as you type in a text input and outputs the result:

**jquery.slug.js:**

```
jQuery.fn.slug = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        events: 'keypress keyup blur',
        targets: ['#slug', '#hidden']
    };
    var opts  = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);

    jQuery(this).on(opts.events, function(){
      var slug = $(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, '-').replace(/-$/, '').replace(/^-/, '');

      jQuery.each(opts.targets, function(index, element) {
        $(element).val(slug);  // input or textarea
        $(element).html(slug); // other dom elements
      });
    });
};
```

**Usage:**

```
$('input[name="some-text-input"]').slug({targets: ['#some-id', 'input[name="some-name"]']});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted. As opposite to the accepted answer above, this solution actually removes non alphanumeric characters and adjacent dashes from the output.

Answer (score 2):

```js
/* Try this one */

function handleize(text) {
    return text.toString().toLowerCase()
               .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
               .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
               .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
               .replace(/^-+/, '')             // Trim - from start of text
               .replace(/-+$/, '');            // Trim - from end of text
}

console.log(handleize("Hello, my name is Corey."));
```